# How to remove -XXXX from Zip Code field using MySQL REGEXP?

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

Can someone give me an example of how to remove anything after a dash "-" in a zip code field using SQL commands?

For example, change any of this:

```
XXXXX-X
XXXXX-
XXXXX-XX
XXXXX-XXXX
```

to this:

```
XXXXX
```

Thanks for the examples. I also need to remove any instances of "-", "-X', "-XXXX", etc in the databases so the zip codes just contain five digits. Can someone include an example of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a regex, you could use MySQL's [`SUBSTRING_INDEX()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) method:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(zip_code, '-', 1) FROM your_table
```

**EDIT** (to support updates)

```
UPDATE your_table SET zip_code = SUBSTRING_INDEX(zip_code, '-', 1);
```

I'd recommend creating a second column, maybe `zip_code_short` and running `SET zip_code_short =` instead of overwriting the main data - just to make sure it doesn't cause any errors first (if feasible).

Comment: Thanks. Please see my update to my post above. I also need a way to remove this from the entries in the database (not just select).

Comment: @Zoolander Updated answer to support `UPDATE`

Answer (score 4):

Given that your field is named `zip` , then just do this:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(zip, '-', 1) as zip
```

that would return what you want.

To update the data on the table you can do:

```
update table set zip = SUBSTRING_INDEX(zip, '-', 1) where condition = foo
```

that would update only records matching some condition, if you want to update them all remove the `where` part

Comment: Thanks. Please see my update to my post above. I also need a way to remove this from the entries in the database (not just select).